# Is it enough to check residuals versus predicted values when assessing linearity assumption in multiple regression?

Tags: regression, residuals, assumptions

Is it enough to check residuals versus predicted values to see if the linearity assumption in multiple linear regression is satisfied?

Because for many predictors, you can't visualize the plot with the outcome variable.

Comment: In general the answer is no. Consider reducing the scope of your question, now it is too general.

Comment: Specifically, can you elaborate on "Because for many predictors, you can't visualize the plot with the outcome variable"?

Comment: I believe a residuals vs. predicted plot helps to asses the assumptions regarding the noise distribution, but not the functional relationship between predictor and predicted (be it linear or not).

Answer (score 2):

A general approach, which also leads to a fix, is to expand predictors as cubic spline functions.  You can either test all the nonlinear terms together to test linearity, or just use the fits as-is (which preserves type I error).